# Почему дочерний элемент переполняет родителя в safari 9.1 flexbox

Tags: css, flexbox

Привет! 
В safari 9.1 есть баг, при котором дочерний блок переполняет по высоте родителя. 
На остальных браузерах все хорошо.

В правой части есть блок b-content js-slider-cont, так вот он переполняет родителя и выталкивает b-content__bottom под экран.
Как поправить?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Safari не понимает min-height: auto нужно использовать min-height: 0